# How do I get 144hz monitor refresh rate to work with the open source ATI driver?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, ati, monitor

With the open source ATI drivers, when I set 144hz in xrandr I get strange full-screen stuttering when I move some windows (especially my chrome browser, but other windows as well).

I don't get these in the proprietary drivers, and xvidtune shows the same modeline for both sets of drivers at 144hz.

**How do I get the Open Source ATI drivers to drive my monitor at 1920x1080@144hz?**

As far as I can tell, both of them are trying to set a very high pixel clock (~325Mhz), however the ATI Proprietary drivers do so without any problems, whereas the open source drivers have trouble. I've tried both the Ubuntu 14.04 vanilla drivers, as well as the xorg-edgers drivers, still with no luck.

120hz runs just fine for both sets of drivers. The "default" in xrandr for the open source drivers is 60hz for some reason.

The reason I am bothering is the proprietary drivers cause Xorg/the computer to freeze when I alt tab from fullscreen games (after a few times, sometimes the first time), but the open source drivers don't.

Environment/hardware:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- Gigabyte Radeon R9 270x
- BenQ XL2720Z (144hz 1920x1080)

Here is the modeline I am trying to set (according to `xvidtune -show` after I use xrandr to set the refresh rate). It shows up the same in both the proprietary driver and the open source driver with the same values:

```
"1920x1080"   325.08   1920 1944 1976 2056   1080 1083 1088 1098 +hsync +vsync
```

And here is the xrandr command I'm using to set the refresh rate:

```
xrandr --rate 144
```

Comment: Semi-dupe question: http://superuser.com/questions/803977/144hz-monitor-linux-open-source-radeon-driver

Comment: Info that could help: I have the same problem with Ubuntu 14.04 but with a nvidia card (Geforce GTX 660) and an Asus VG248QE monitor which is also able to run at 144 Hz. I can't change the refresh rate at all, meaning that I'm stuck at 60 Hz.

Comment: 1000 views, no answers. I think the xorg-edgers ended up working for me eventually? I forget though. Then I got sick of some of the tweakiness, and the fact that I couldn't get it to stick witout xrandr, and then I found the high refresh rate monitor black-frame tweaking software isn't supported on Linux, so I went back to Windows. /sigh